# Alta registro cabecera y detalle - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy desarrollando una web de pedidos y dispongo de 2 tablas pedido y detalle de pedidos.
He creado dos modelos con laravel Pedido y PedidoDetalle.
Dispongo de un formulario y pulsando a un botón se añade un artículo al pedido:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach ($productos as $prod)
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>'PedidoDetalleController@store',$prod->idPRODUCTOS))}}
{{Form::token()}}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href=""> <!-- Enlace con ficha de producto -->
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <img class="card-img-top"  src="{{asset('imagenes/productos/'.$prod->IMAGEN)}}" width="195" height="195" alt="{{ $prod->NOMBRE }}">
            <div class="card-body align-content-center">
```

En el controlador del detalle del pedido, intento mirar si ese usuario ya dispone de un pedido en curso y si es así solamente doy de alta el detalle y si no existe doy de alta cabecera y detalle.

El problema es que al intentar averiguar si ya existe un pedido (cabecera), al hacer el select count(*) de la tabla pedido nunca me devuelve nada y solamente da de alta el detalle.

Lo intento haciendo lo siguiente:

```
public function store(PedidoDetalleFormRequest $request)
{
    $usuario=auth()->user()->id;
    echo $usuario;
    $pedido= new Pedido;
    $count = DB::table('pedidos')
                ->where(['idUSUARIOS' => $usuario])
                ->count();
    /*$count = Pedido::where('idUSUARIOS',$usuario)->count();*/
    $detalle=new PedidoDetalle;
    if ($count>0){
        $idPedido = DB::table('pedidos')->where(['idUSUARIOS' => $usuario])->first();
        $detalle->idPEDIDOS=$idPedido;
    }
    $detalle->idPRODUCTOS=$request->get('idPRODUCTOS');
    $precio=$request->get('precio');
    $detalle->precio=$precio*0.79;
    $detalle->impuesto=$precio*0.21;

    /* Alta de registro en la tabla pedido */
    if ($count=0) {
        $session_id = Session::getId();
        $pedido->session=$session_id;
        $pedido->idUSUARIOS=$usuario;
        $pedido->save();
    }

    $detalle->save();

    //Redireccionamos a la ruta usuario
    return Redirect::to('home');
}
```

Pero también lo he intentado de la forma que se ve en el anterior código comentado. En lugar de utilizar DB utilizo el modelo Pedido.

En todos los casos el resultado es el mismo y solamente da de alta el detalle y no la cabecera.

¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema o estoy haciendo algo mal?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: `if($count == 0)`

Te falta un `=`

Comment: Hola Didac, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además, cambia las imagenes por el texto del codigo. Es mas legible y asi no hay barreras para gente que tenga bloqueadas las imagenes, o poca conexion. Para formatear el codigo selecionalo y pulsa `ctrl + k`. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias!! Sigo tus comentarios.

Comment: ¿Podrias colocar la definición de tus tablas? ¿la columna se llama `idUSUARIOS`? Pienso que quizá la columna se llame `idUSUARIO` ya que no creo que un pedido tenga mas de 1 usuario.

Comment: hacé un `dd($count);` para ver que es exactamente lo que está devolviendo esa consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por las respuestas recibidas.

El problema era el que comenta FederHico, que no hacía correctamente el if($count==0) (menudo error!!), entonces nunca entraba en esa condición y por tanto no creaba nunca la cabecera.